# Add default value to enum type field in schema builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, enums, database-schema

I'm using the following method to create a database column of type `ENUM` in schema builder:

```
$table->enum('status', array('new', 'active', 'disabled'));
```

I'd like to set it's default value to `active`.
I tried to do this:

```
$table->enum('status', array('new', 'active', 'disabled'))->default('active');
```

But as you can guess it doesn't set it's default value. I'm using a MySQL database if that's important.

Answer (score 17):

From [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html):

> If an ENUM column is declared to permit NULL, the NULL value is a legal value for the column, and the default value is NULL. If an ENUM column is declared NOT NULL, its default value is the first element of the list of permitted values.

I'm assuming this means you should set `'active'` as the first value, remove the `default()` call, and possibly set `NULL` permittance manually.

Comment: Thanks, should have checked the manual first, thought it was a Laravel thing. Will accept as soon as the time limit lets me.

Comment: You mean remove `NULL` permission, isntead of setting it, right?

Comment: The answer is over three years old @Adam, but I probably meant that you might have to explicitly set whether to allow null or not.

Answer (score 16):

use this :

```
$table->enum('status',['new', 'active', 'disabled'])->default('active');
```

Comment: this is worked for me. i'm using laravel 7.30.4 with postgresql

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue, that's what worked for me:

```
$table->enum('status', array('active', 'new', 'disabled'));
```

Place the default value as the first element in the array. `active` is now the default value.